# Registering Assemblies used In SQL CLR Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, assemblies, clr, integration

I have been messing around with writing some stored procedures in .NET code with SQL CLR Integration.  In the stored procedure, I am calling a third-party dll.  When I try to create the assembly in SQL Server containing my custom stored proc, it complains that the third-party dll is not registered with the database.

Is there some way I can call the dll without registering it in SQL Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't use an assembly that isn't in the [Approved Assembly list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx), or that isn't registered in the database.  You can't even load it into the GAC to access it, it has to explicitly be added to SQL Server using CREATE ASSEMBLY.  Why don't you want to load the assembly into the database?  What is it doing that you need in SQL?  I ask because there may be a different solution to your problem that is a better fit.

Answer (score 4):

The third party assembly must be pre-deployed to the server.  Look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345099.aspx) for instructions on deploying the assembly to the server.